# What kinds of problem do we have with this program?(OpenMP) how to svoid it?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, race-condition

Following is my code and i wanna know why there will happen the problem with "race-condition" and how to solve this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    int a = 123;

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)

    {

        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        int b = (thread_id + 1)*10;

        a += b;

    }

    std::cout << “a = “ << a << “\n”;

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A race condition occurs when two or more threads access shared data and at least one of them changes its value at the same time. In your code this line cause a race condition:

```
a += b;
```

`a` is a shared variable and updated by 2 threads simultaneously, so the final result may be incorrect. Note that depending on the hardware used, possible race condition does not necessarily means that a data race actually will occur, so the result may be correct, but it is a semantic error in your code.

To fix it you have 2 options:

1. use atomic operation:

```
#pragma omp atomic
a += b;
```

2. use reduction:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) reduction(+:a)
```